# Java How to use draw arc and connect to another arc

Tags: java, applet, awt, paint

I am really confuse in how to use this drawArc thing in java. I Have a Case Problem and I need to draw Patrick(From Spongebob Squarepants), and for me the only way to draw patrick is by using ARCS! but I really dont know how to use it , any suggestion guys in how to draw patrick please guys I really Need Your Help. By the way this is what I've done for a while

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.applet.*;

public class CaseProblemPatrickpaint extends Applet{

    public void paint(Graphics aw){    
        setSize(500,500);
        aw.drawArc(10, 200, 40, 40, 100, 100);    
    }
}//it is just the left hand. no arm including
```

sorry for this code but this is what I can do for now cause I'm having a problem using drawArc :'(

[image]

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tpgdw.jpg): https://i.stack.imgur.com/7u4sT.jpg by the way this is what i am going to draw
.
I really want to now this drawArc thing guys

Comment: please search here by using tags, Java + Swing + Image + paintComponent, easier Java + Swing + Image + JLabel, and order by newest

Answer (score 0):

A good example of draw arc is on the [Oracle documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/geometry/primitives.html).  You could use an ellipse for the body (as per the same link) and have overlapping arcs, then simply use a pink background colour for it all to hide the overlaps.